# How to show a image array in a json file

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I have an array with images in a JSON file and I want to show a slideshow thing, I want to show them through a java class, I search on the internet, in a forum and didn´t find anything, any help is useful. Thanks. 
JSON file:

```
{
    "slides": [
        {"imagem": "C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Desktop\\Escola\\Estágio 12º\\fotos\\imagem1.jpg"},
    {"imagem": "C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Desktop\\Escola\\Estágio 12º\\fotos\\imagem2.jpg"},
    {"imagem": "C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Desktop\\Escola\\Estágio 12º\\fotos\\imagem3.jpg"}
    ]
}
```

Java file:

```
package estagio;
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JSONjava {   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Estagio\\src\\estagio\\JSONexample.json"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while    (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        String json = sb.toString();

        JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(json);
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray slides = obj.getAsJsonArray("slides");       

        int numarray = slides.size();
        System.out.println(numarray);       

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < numarray ; i = i + 1){

        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: You have reached so far, and yet there is no coding attempt in the for block? Oh come'on ...

Comment: I tried a few things but I don´t know if they are right so I didn´t put them. But they also didn´t do anything so, no need to put that code here.

Comment: Just a note, JsonParser().parse() can parse a java.io.Reader as well. So rather than reading the file and putting the content into a string which you then pass to parse(json), you could do .parse(new FileReader("/my/json.json"))

Comment: What you mean is, instead of having `JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(json);` I should have `JsonElemnt element = .parse(new FileReader("/my/json.json"));`? Or you´re saying to substitute `scanner`

Comment: Oh, I already understand what you said about using `FileReader`

Comment: But now, how can I show the images?